# How can I send dictionary data from client side to python server for comparison with df2 using socket programming?

Tags: python, json, sockets, dictionary

I am facing an issue with socket programming. This is a server-side python program where I received df1 data from the client-side which is in dictionary format. How can I receive the same data from both sides that is df1 and df2?

```
import socket
import sys 


def server_program():
    HOST = '192.168.0.115' 
    PORT = 8888

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    print('socket created')

    try:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error as err:
        print('Bind Failed, Error Code: ' + str(err[0]) + ', Message: ' + err[1])
        sys.exit()

    print('Socket Bind Success!')

    s.listen(10)
    print ('Socket is now listening')


    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print ('Connect with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
        df1 = conn.recv(1024)
        print(df1)
        conn.close()
        break
    s.close()


    df2 = {"name":"rajat", "place":"rajasthan"} # here I put df2 equals to the df1 to get compared.
    print(df2)

    if df1 == df2:
        print('yes Data Exists')
    else:
        print('No Data')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_program()
```

client-side.py

```
import socket
import sys
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('192.168.0.115', 8888)) #IP is the server IP

for args in sys.argv:
    if args == '':
        args = 'no args'
    else:
        df1 = {"name":"rajat", "place":"rajasthan"}
        s.sendall(df1)
print('Data is sent to the server!!')
```

The output which I am receiving is:-

```
C:\Users\Pallavai\Desktop>python ese.py
socket created
Socket Bind Success!
Socket is now listening
Connect with 192.168.0.115:56105
{"name":"rajat", "place":"rajasthan"}
{'name': 'rajat', 'place': 'rajasthan'}
No Data

Why these both are not same as df2 is directly printed.
```

Comment: The two dictionaries are different, is that the problem?

Comment: Because one is a `dict` and the other one is an `str` ? Try `import ast; df1 = ast.literal_eval(df1)` Although, i am not sure passing objects like this is a good idea

Comment: Can you help me how to compare both as JSON objects?

Comment: it can't work - you would have to convert data to bytes to send. And when you receive you have bytes/string which you would have to convert to dictionary

Comment: use keyword 'cmp' to compare dict, as in your case it is comparing dict as string datatypes. cmp (df1, df2). Posted a solution below, please check.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing a `dict` with a `str`, that's why the comparison fails.

Maybe, `pickle` the data and send it and decode it appropriately on the server.

In this case, using JSON to encode and decode is appropriate.

Like, in the server side,

```
import json
...
print ('Connect with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
df1 = conn.recv(1024)
df1 = json.loads(df1.decode('utf-8')) # decode the dict from JSON
conn.close()
...
```

And in the client side,

```
import json
...
df1 = {"name":"rajat", "place":"rajasthan"}
s.sendall(json.dumps(df1).encode('utf-8')) # encode the dict to JSON
...
```

Comment: Its showing error 

s.sendall(json.dumps(df1))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I forgot to use `python3`. Updated the answer : )

Comment: No problem. Glad to be able to help : )

Comment: Can i ask you one more question related to this query?

Comment: Sure. Please : )

Comment: In the client side if the df2 is like= 
(1, 'black', '2345678jhbv', 'eghji876', 3.0, datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 4, 0, 0)) in this format.  How can i compare this one

Comment: The usual way is to convert the `datetime` to a `str`. You can do that using by using a custom `encoder` in the `json.dumps` like `json.dumps(dict, default=myconverter)` and the decode in the other side, and convert the `datetime` object back from `str`. Note `myconverter` is a custom user defined function, please check the documentation of `json` for more

Comment: Ok I will tell u what the exact thing is going on:
I got df1 as I mention above in the same format.
on the other hand, I got df2 from MySQL query which is also the same as df1. I just want to do comparison between both objects.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use cmp to compare dictionary. I have added code for comparing two dictionary.

```
import socket
import sys 


def server_program():
    HOST = '192.168.0.115' 
    PORT = 8888

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


    print('socket created')

    try:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error as err:
        print('Bind Failed, Error Code: ' + str(err[0]) + ', Message: ' + err[1])
        sys.exit()

    print('Socket Bind Success!')

    s.listen(10)
    print ('Socket is now listening')


    while True:
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print ('Connect with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
        df1 = conn.recv(1024)
        print(df1)
        conn.close()
        break
    s.close()


    df2 = {"name":"rajat", "place":"rajasthan"} # here I put df2 equals to the df1 to get compared.
    print(df2)

    res = cmp(df1, df2)
    print(res) # If both are equal, it will print 0 else -1
    if res == 0:
        print('yes Data Exists')
    else:
        print('No Data')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_program()
```

Comment: I double checked, it is working. try cmp(df1, df2). It should work.